I am trying to create a driver scrapper for Lenovo drivers I am stummped at this one spot
import csv
import time
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests
from tabulate import tabulate

product_series = "thinkpad-x-series-laptops"
product_code = "thinkpad-x1-carbon-11th-gen-type-21hm-21hn"
lenovo_api = "https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/api/v4/downloads/drivers?"

headers = {
    "referer": f"https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/{product_series}/{product_code}/downloads/driver-list/",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/131.0.0.0",
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
}
payload = {
    "productId": f"laptops-and-netbooks/{product_series}/{product_code}",
}

updates_data = requests.get(f"{lenovo_api}{urlencode(payload)}", headers=headers).json()

row_headers = [
    "Name", "Release Date", "Version",
    "Update status", "File Type", "URL",
    "Description",
]

rows = [
    [
        driver['NAME'],
        driver['DATE'],
        driver['VERSION'],
        driver['PRIORITY'],
        driver['TypeString'],
        driver['URL'],
        driver['SUMARY'],
    ] for driver in updates_data["DownloadData"]
]

I do not ubnderstand where to get this part from "DownloadData" in
] for driver in updates_data["DownloadData"]
I keep getting the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:/Users/EDMTC7J4/Desktop/Lenovo Driver Scraper/rryh1.py", line 38,
in 
] for driver in updates_data["DownloadData"] KeyError: 'DownloadData'

I have worked on this based upon the post here
I am trying to use python and selenium to create a driver scraper, I need to grab particular data from the web page and put it in csv row and column
I just need help understanding what to put where "DownloadData" is and I am having difficulty figuring it out.

It's giving KeyError because DownloadData does not exist in updates_data. There is a different key called DownloadItems, and I'm assuming that what you need.
print(updates_data['body'].keys())

>>> dict_keys(['AllCategories', 'AllOperatingSystems', 'AllPriorities', 'DownloadItems', 'ProductId', 'DCGFixIDNamingGuideImageUrl', 'RestrictCountryList'])

You'll need to explore the dictionary further to access the specific fields you're looking for, i.e. updates_data['body']['DownloadItems']['Files']. In other words, a nested loop to go through each Files of each DownloadItems. Then you can organize the row items however you want.
rows = []
for driver in updates_data['body']['DownloadItems']:
    for f in driver['Files']:
        rows.append([
            f['Name'],
            f['Date'],
            f['Version'],
            f['Priority'],
            f['TypeString'],
            f['URL'],
            driver['Summary'],
        ])

Output
from pprint import pprint

pprint(rows[:2])

>>> [['Lenovo System Update',
  {'Unix': 1722348780000},
  '5.08.03.59',
  'Recommended',
  'EXE',
  'https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/thinkvantage_en/system_update_5.08.03.59.exe',
  'System Update enables IT administrators to distribute updates for software, '
  'drivers, and BIOS in a managed environment from a local server.'],
 ['README',
  {'Unix': 1722348840000},
  '5.08.03.59',
  'Recommended',
  'TXT README',
  'https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/thinkvantage_en/system_update_5.08.03.59.txt',
  'System Update enables IT administrators to distribute updates for software, '
  'drivers, and BIOS in a managed environment from a local server.']]

Example of an item from DownloadItems.
pprint(updates_data['body']['DownloadItems'][0])

>>> {'AlertDataLoss': False,
 'Audiences': [{'Id': 'ANONYMOUS', 'Name': 'Anonymous'}],
 'Brocade': False,
 'Category': {'Classify': 'dl-category-thinkvantage',
              'ID': '8FA7E883-9036-4E57-A106-3C9FA89F1490',
              'Name': 'ThinkVantage Technology'},
 'Countries': [],
 'Date': {'Unix': 1722348720000},
 'DocId': 'DS012808',
 'Eods': '0',
 'Files': [{'Date': {'Unix': 1722348780000},
            'FileName': '',
            'HasReadme': False,
            'MD5': 'd54563ebb7080b18959146c102d52f26',
            'Name': 'Lenovo System Update',
            'OperatingSystemKeys': [],
            'Priority': 'Recommended',
            'PriorityWeight': 2,
            'ReadmeUrl': '',
            'Released': None,
            'SHA1': '11cddb61f89b850e053a6f476a4eea855c9133a8',
            'SHA256': 'e66794dc561a3e58e3dc68556eb053ee32b674ac9d99638e473ef7322f353e0d',
            'Size': '10.1 MB',
            'TypeEnString': '',
            'TypeString': 'EXE',
            'URL': 'https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/thinkvantage_en/system_update_5.08.03.59.exe',
            'Version': '5.08.03.59'},
           {'Date': {'Unix': 1722348840000},
            'FileName': '',
            'HasReadme': False,
            'MD5': '1ad005136b60036a9420211698db5935',
            'Name': 'README',
            'OperatingSystemKeys': [],
            'Priority': 'Recommended',
            'PriorityWeight': 2,
            'ReadmeUrl': '',
            'Released': None,
            'SHA1': '45cf2bad1e60565a0ecf0851d3d3caea7bf9ea3c',
            'SHA256': '1f0c6e404aa47d7ed24673c908ab1c7a81b26e7debe741ad1cf0a2e8d0e9f152',
            'Size': '16.3 KB',
            'TypeEnString': '',
            'TypeString': 'TXT README',
            'URL': 'https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/thinkvantage_en/system_update_5.08.03.59.txt',
            'Version': '5.08.03.59'}],
 'FixID': '',
 'Highlight': False,
 'Hit': '6580855',
 'ID': ['DS012808-LENOVO-SYSTEM-UPDATE-FOR-WINDOWS-10-7-32-BIT-64-BIT-DESKTOP-NOTEBOOK-WORKSTATION',
        'DS012808',
        'D295217D-1898-40AB-94CD-A729A310EBB0'],
 'InWarranty': False,
 'LanguageCode': 'en',
 'MetaData': 'System Update, TVSU, Updater, Software Installer, SWI, think '
             'vantage system update,lenovo system update service cpu,DS012808',
 'OEMOnly': False,
 'OperatingSystemKeys': ['Windows 10 (32-bit)',
                         'Windows 10 (64-bit)',
                         'Windows 11 (32-bit)',
                         'Windows 11 (64-bit)',
                         'Windows 7 (32-bit)',
                         'Windows 7 (64-bit)'],
 'PNCheck': False,
 'RebootRequired': 0,
 'RedirectCode': 0,
 'RedirectTo': '',
 'RequireLogin': False,
 'RestrictedCountries': [],
 'SEOH1Content': 'Lenovo System Update for Windows 11, 10 & 7 (32-bit, 64-bit) '
                 '- Desktop, Notebook, Workstation',
 'Summary': 'System Update enables IT administrators to distribute updates for '
            'software, drivers, and BIOS in a managed environment from a local '
            'server.',
 'SummaryInfo': {'Priority': 'Recommended', 'Version': '5.08.03.59'},
 'Title': 'Lenovo System Update for Windows 11, 10 & 7 (32-bit, 64-bit) - '
          'Desktop, Notebook, Workstation',
 'Updated': {'Unix': 1722348888000},
 'rolePass': True}


Ok, thank you very much for that information. You are great!
